# How do I retrieve all text in an HTML DOM but exclude SCRIPT and STYLE tags?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I know how to quickly extract text nodes from a DOM:

```
document.evaluate('//text()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
```

But is there an easy way to exclude text from SCRIPT, STYLE, or other tags that are not shown to the user?

Something like:

```
'//text()[ parent.name not in ("SCRIPT", "STYLE") ]'
```

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 7):

```
//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides Nick Jones correct answer, for more complex exclusion you should use XPath node set exclusion expression:

```
$ns1[not(count(.|$ns2)=count($ns2))]
```

In this case:

```
//*[not(count(.|//script|/*/*/style)=count(//script|/*/*/style))]/text()
```