# XPath to find nodes with text + all their descendants & siblings that match certain criteria

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, greasemonkey

**Background:**
I'm trying to improve on a [Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/13520) I found.
The script marks prices in foreign currencies and can translate them into the currency of your choice.

**The main problem:**
How to make the script handle when prices are listed with tags, such as:

```
<b><i>9.</i></b><sup>95</sup>EUR
```

(Newegg.com does this, for example - they write their prices like so: <span>$</span>174<sup>.99</sup>).

Currently, the script only finds prices that are listed in the same text node since the XPath expression being used is:

```
document.evaluate("//text()", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
```

Since the script needs to be fast, I'm trying to avoid stepping through the DOM too much...
**Are there any XPath gurus who could help out with some smart solutions for this purpose?**

  
**More detailed description of the problem:**
The code I now have for finding the text nodes:

```
var re_skip = /^(SCRIPT|IFRAME|TEXTAREA|STYLE|OPTION|TITLE|HEAD|NOSCRIPT)$/;  // List of elements whose text node-children can be skipped
text = document.evaluate("//text()", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var i = text.snapshotLength;
while (i--) {
    el = text.snapshotItem(i);
    if (!el.parentNode || re_skip.test(el.parentNode.nodeName.toUpperCase()) || el.parentNode.className == 'autocurrency') {
        continue;
    }
//  ...
//  (RegEx logic to check if prices can be found in the text)
}
```

- The check to discard text nodes whose parent elements are listed in "re_skip" could be done in the XPath expression as well ([using the "not" notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657146/how-do-i-retrieve-all-text-in-an-html-dom-but-exclude-script-and-style-tags)), right? And this would give a speed-increase?
- If an ordered XPath type is used instead, I guess I no longer will have to include a check to see if the parent of the text node being parsed is <span class="autocurrency"> (that is, the <span> that the script adds around matched prices).
- If I've understood things correctly, normalize-space() (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812465/xpath-search-through-html-tags)), cannot be used in this case, since the script adds a <span class="autocurrency"> around the matched amount and we need to retain the correct index for where this <span> should be entered.
- Is there a way for the XPath to allow only certain (inline) elements to be used in-between the currency values? Or perhaps it could do this: **"when a node containing text is found, also include all of its children (and their children and so on) in the match - *unless* the child node is a block type element."  (or perhaps it should read: "...unless the child node is a DIV, P, TABLE, or any of the elements in re_skip")**

I can re-write the regex to handle text such as "<span>$</span>174<sup>.99</sup>" as long as I *find* these text strings - preferably using XPath, as I have understood this to be much faster than stepping through the DOM.

Thank you very much in advance for any help you can give me with this!
 
**--------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT:**
OK, I realize now that the question could do with some clarification and some examples, so here they come.  A web page might look something like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <span>9.95 <span>EUR</span></span><br />
    <span>8.<sup>95</sup></span>AU$<br />
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Bla</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>7</b>.95kr</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>Bla bla</div>
    6.95 <span>GBP</span>
  </div>
  <div><img src="" /><img src=""><span>Bla bla bla</span></div>
</body>
```

Now, in that example, the overhead isn't that great - I could just feed the whole source code, as a string, directly to the regex that finds prices. But normally, pages will have lots of non-text elements that would make the script very slow if I didn't use a fast XPath to parse out the texts. So, I'm looking for an XPath expression that would find the different texts in the example above, *but not **just** the text content* - since we also need tags that might surround parts of a price (a new <span> will later be created around the matched price, including any inline elements that might surround parts of the price).

I don't know exactly what the XPath could be made to return, but *somehow* I need to grab a hold of the following strings from the example page above:

```
"9.95 <span>EUR</span>"       (or possibly: "<span>9.95 <span>EUR</span></span>")
"<span>8.<sup>95</sup></span>AU$"
"Bla"                         (or possibly: "<th>Bla</th>")
"<b>7</b>.95kr"               (or possibly: "<td><b>7</b>.95kr</td>")
"Bla bla"                     (or possibly: "<div>Bla bla</div>")
"6.95 <span>GBP</span>"
"Bla bla bla"                 (or possibly: "<span>Bla bla bla</span>")
```

and then these strings can be parsed by the regex that finds prices.

Comment: This question would make more sence if you provide a representative, complete (but not unnecessarily large) XML document and clearly point out the tect nodes that you want to be selected. Failing to do so makes this a bad example of a good question.

Comment: Excuse me, what are you talking about? I thought I had clearly marked this as a question pertaining to Greasemonkey, JavaScript, HTML, and XPath. I thought it was clear that this Greasemonkey JavaScript is run on web pages (HTML). I even mentioned which kind of HTML elements were likely to be encountered (even though the script should not hard-code which elements are allowed - just which ones that *aren't*)

Comment: OK, after reading through the text a couple of times I realize that it *does* need some adjustment and some clarifying. I will edit the question.

Comment: Maybe it would help to know that XPath only operates on XML (Infoset) and not on HTML -- the intersection of these two is XHTML. As for Javascript and all sort of monkeys, don't expect XPath experts to know much about them. If you want an XPath expression to select specific nodes, you must: 1. Provide the XML document; 2. Define unambiguously the nodes that should be selected. Failing to provide these is equivalent to seeking an advice about the weather tomorrow.

Comment: I just edited the question with some clarification and an example. After doing so, I now see your latest comment and all I can say is: I am sorry if I have misunderstood what the term "XPath expression" stands for. I thought it could be used for the type of "document.evaluate()" call mentioned above - which clearly works on HTML since the Greasemonkey script using this code works on HTML pages.

Comment: OK, Now it's much better. One last question: Why do you need such nodes that have nothing to do with the prices, such as: `<th>Bla</th>`, `<div>Bla bla</div> ` and `span>Bla bla bla</span>` ? Also, what should be the exact logic in selecting the wanted nodes? Seems that you want every text node that contains a number or starts with a number, together with its parent element and its first sibling that doesn't contain a number. Even if this is so, in some cases the result would be a very-top element that represents almost the complete document -- e.g. the parent `div` for `6.95 <span>GBP</span>`

Comment: Actually, as the script looks today, it uses a separate regular expression that does the actual parsing (finding of prices) in the strings provided by the XPath expression. I guess this regex logic could instead be moved to where the XPath expression does its magic, but as it works now we just get all the text node strings from the XPath. This was sufficient before I realized that some sites place tags that break up the text nodes with the prices (such as 9<i>GBP</i>) - now that whole "price string" is needed, incl. the tags themselves, as the script creates a span around the price.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can certainly use a path like `//*[not(self::script | self::textarea | self::style)]//text()` to find only those text node descendants of element nodes that are not one of "script", "textarea", "style". So the regular expression test you have is not necessary, you could express that requirement with XPath. Whether that performs better I can't tell, you will have to check with the XPath implementations of the browser(s) you want to use the Greasemonkey script with.

Comment: Thank you, Martin, for confirming the idea I mentioned about using the "not" notation to exclude certain elements. Hopefully you, or someone else, have some idea about the main issue I brought up too - to include not only the text from each individual text node, but to also include its children (including their tags - not just their text content). Thanks again!